# Why do I need constCast here, is there better way?

Tags: zig

What am I doing wrong in this example? In `deinit()` I am getting an error that expected is `*MemoryPool` but `*const MemoryPool` was given.

```js
const Tree = struct {
    node_pool: std.heap.MemoryPool(Node),
    pub fn init(allocator: Allocator) Tree {
        var node_pool = std.heap.MemoryPool(Node).init(allocator);
        return Tree{ .node_pool = node_pool };
    }
    pub fn deinit(self: Tree) void {
        self.node_pool.deinit(); // <-- error: * is expected, *const is given
    }
};
```

I'm working around the error with `@constCast()` but this feels strange - I don't fully understand why I'm doing this and I assume I might be doing something very much wrong. Is there a way to avoid it? Am I missing something?

```js
const Tree = struct {
    ...

    pub fn deinit(self: Tree) void {
        @constCast(&self.node_pool).deinit();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function parameters are [immutable](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Pass-by-value-Parameters) in Zig. That's why there's `const`.

You need to provide `deinit` with a pointer to `Tree`:

```
pub fn deinit(self: *Tree) void {
    self.node_pool.deinit();
}
```

Additionally, you can do `self.* = undefined` to [invalidate](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#undefined) a specific `Tree` instance. This is [commonly](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/108b3c5673908057df7b96cec61d9bcadaa9f197/lib/std/heap/memory_pool.zig#L83) done by STD types.

Comment: Earlier I changed from `*Tree` to `Tree` without thinking too much ‍♂️ as I was getting compile error earlier of same kind. Reason was because I declared my tree instance using `const tree = Tree.init(...)`. Changed it now to `var tree = Tree.init(...)` and problems gone. Thank you.